# Big Sorting - One implementation works . Other two dont work

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda

Why is the below code for Big sorting hackerrank not working ?
 i took help from geeksForGeeks to sort in a particular order
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-a-vector-in-c/

vector bigSorting(vector unsorted) {

```
bool compare(string &a,string &b){
    return a.length()<b.length()||a.length()==b.length()&&a<b
}

sort(unsorted.begin(),unsorted.end(),compare);

return unsorted;
```

Errors are below

8   38  D:\Dev Cpp\bigsort.cpp  [Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

12  42  D:\Dev Cpp\bigsort.cpp  [Error] 'compare' was not declared in this scope

i already know the below working version

```
sort(unsorted.begin(),unsorted.end(),[](const string &a,const string &b)->bool{
        return a.length()<b.length() ||  a<b&&a.length()==b.length() ;
    });`
    `return unsorted;
```

another implementation is given below . It gives time limit error for some cases .

```
int size=unsorted.size();string t;

for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++){
        // according to length
        if(unsorted[j].size()<unsorted[i].size()){
             t=unsorted[j];
             unsorted[j]=unsorted[i];
             unsorted[i]=t;
        }
        //dictionary sort
        if((unsorted[j]<unsorted[i])&&(unsorted[j].size()==unsorted[i].size())){
             t=unsorted[j];
             unsorted[j]=unsorted[i];
             unsorted[i]=t;`
        }
    }
}

return unsorted;
```

Sorry for asking so many questions in one . I want to know the difference between working version and the two non - working versions .

Comment: Focus your eyes on the lambda, then on the sorting function. Print them out on two sheets of paper and put them next to each to compare. You should immediately see something so glaringly obvious, such an apparent, clear-cut difference, that you will be wondering how you missed something obvious, in the first place. The difference is right there, in plain sight. There are no tricks there. Keep in mind that every keyword in C++ has a specific purpose and it means something. It's not just to make the code look pretty.

Comment: *It gives time limit error for some cases* -- The probable reason is that you've implemented one of the worst sorting algorithms for large data sets -- the bubble sort.  Imagine if `size` was 1000 -- you would looping a million times.